# how to use woocommerce shortcodes in php mail function

Tags: wordpress

```
if(isset($_POST["submit-cart"])){
    $first_name = $_POST['your-first-name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['your-last-name'];
    $email = $_POST['your-email'];
    $phone = $_POST['your-phone'];
    $location = $_POST['your-location'];
    $suburb = $_POST['your-suburb'];
    $industry = $_POST['your-industry'];
    $business = $_POST['your-business'];
    $message = $_POST['your-message'];


    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Thank you for contacting us";
    $msg=  do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_cart]' );


 $message ="
<html> 
  <body> 
    {$msg}
  </body>
</html>";

    $headers = "From: $from";

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
      echo "<script>alert('Email successfully sent');</script>";
    }
}
```

I am receiving mail but in terms of code not design I tried to solve this issue but it sending as it is. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanking You.

Comment: Can you post a preview of the received mail, what you're asking is not clear for me.

Comment: I am getting full html code instead of design

Comment: $msg this is my html code i am getting as it is in mail

Comment: Can you please tell me